# Automatically Wake PC at certain time without wake-on-lan

Tags: scheduled-tasks, wake-on-lan, task-scheduler, wake-up

I feel like this shouldn't be too difficult. I want my PC to turn on at 7:00 AM every morning. I have a Toshiba satellite L50-B-1LN running windows 8. It uses UEFI instead of a normal BIOS. In there were settings for wake-on-lan, wake-on-ac, wake-on-screen-opening, but no wake on time. I cant use wake on lan because I use the WIFI provided by my uni. Is there any way around this? This seems like such a simple task but I can't find any information on the Web.

Comment: Do you have any "resume" or "alarm" or "power state" options. Sometimes wake timers have odd names in BIOS/UEFI. You could set a scheduled task to wake the computer but you'd have to put the computer to sleep (I think) so that the task can wake the computer. Shutdown or hibernate, I'm unsure if they'll work because they're deeper sleeps than just "sleep".

Comment: I'm afraid not, the only wake options are the ones I mentioned. How would I create a scheduled task to wake the computer from sleep? I am using both Windows 8 and Kubuntu, could I do it in either of these?